# Better switch/mux type for laser diode

Tags: relay, multiplexer, laser, analog-switch

I recently designed and tested a laser driver board which can generate max 200mA current. One of the requirement was to be able switch that current source between 4 laser diode channels. I used ADG1404 mux to switch the current and NC relays for each channel to short laser diode leads as ESD protection.
The main reason to choose ADG1404 is its max continuous current and its low charge injection. During switching, almost no negative spikes are measured on laser diode.

However, in the next phase, I need to generate 500mA current which is fine but also switch that current between 4 channels. There are some SPST switches from ADI which can pass 500mA current but their charge injection are high enough to create relatively big negative voltage spike which might damage the laser diode.

By the way, laser diodes forward voltage that I drive can be anything between 1V to 7V. Also I use laser diodes in the low side so cathode is connected to ground.

Do you think that I should use directly 4 SPDT relays rather than mux? I do not have too much experience with relays. As long as, switching time is less than 10ms, that is fine. (at least for now)

As I said, my concern is negative voltage spikes that might destroy laser diode. Does anybody has experience or know what kind of switch is better for this laser driver application?

Thank you.